# Where did those people come from in this SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello if anyone can advise me on this please cause I have been stuck for a while. I am required to show the people that were in a location id 1 on a certain date, based on if they did a transaction or not, from both Employees and Customers. When checking the data manually there is only 2 transactions and 3 people involved:

```
SELECT * FROM CS_store.Transactions
WHERE date = '2021-09-07' AND l_id = 1;
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDgSl.png)

But when I wrote my code, a bunch of people I have no idea where they came, claim to meet all criteria. Why?:

```
CREATE VIEW PeopleInShop AS 
SELECT e.birth_day, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.date, l.l_id
FROM Employees e,Customers c, Transactions t , Locations l
WHERE l.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07'
UNION
SELECT c.birth_day, c.first_name, c.last_name, t.date, l.l_id
FROM Employees e, Customers c , Transactions t , Locations l
WHERE l.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07' ;

SELECT * FROM PeopleInShop;
```

[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yl4C.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what this: `Employees e,Customers c, Transactions t , Locations l` means?

Comment: @forpas I know that it is a way to shortcut the column. Employees into e and so on

Comment: @CyberWTF if you are joining 2 tables, you need to tell MySQL what fields to join on. Learn about `JOIN` and `ON`

Comment: Read about joins: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: If you do `FROM Employees e,Customers c, Transactions t , Locations l` You are doing a FULL JOIN, in your case with no linking limitations, look it up, it will explain why you have SOoooo many results returned

Comment: Also I suspect you need employees in first part of union (not employees and customers) and customers in second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables together, otherwise you will get the Cartesian product of all your tables. I had to guess some of your columns but something like this should work:

```
CREATE VIEW PeopleInShop AS 
SELECT e.birth_day, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.date, l.l_id
FROM Employees e,Transactions t , Locations l
WHERE l.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07'
AND t.e_id = e.e_id AND t.l_id = l.l_id
UNION
SELECT c.birth_day, c.first_name, c.last_name, t.date, l.l_id
FROM Customers c , Transactions t , Locations l
WHERE l.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07' 
AND t.c_id = c.c_id AND t.l_id = l.l_id ;

SELECT * FROM PeopleInShop;
```

In fact, if I guessed your columns correctly then you don't need the locations table at all since your transactions table will have the location id as a foreign key:

```
CREATE VIEW PeopleInShop AS 
SELECT e.birth_day, e.first_name, e.last_name, t.date, t.l_id
FROM Employees e,Transactions t
WHERE t.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07'
AND t.e_id = e.e_id
UNION
SELECT c.birth_day, c.first_name, c.last_name, t.date, t.l_id
FROM Customers c , Transactions t 
WHERE t.l_id = 1 AND t.date = '2021-09-07' 
AND t.c_id = c.c_id ;
```